sys/user time & childs sys/user time in linux
Based on example 8.31 of APUE, suppose the following code. This example shows user/sys time of a process and also user/sys times of child processes for each command (passed as argvs)
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/times.h>

void do_cmd(int, const char *);
void pr_times(clock_t, clock_t, struct tms *, struct tms *);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        long clktck = 0;

        clktck=sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);

        for (int i=1; i<argc; i++)
                do_cmd(clktck, argv[i]);

        exit (0);
}

void do_cmd(int clktck, const char *cmd) {
        struct tms      tmsstart, tmsend;
        clock_t         start, end;

        start=times(&tmsstart);
        system(cmd);
        end = times(&tmsend);

        printf("command:%s\n", cmd);
        pr_times(clktck, end-start, &tmsstart, &tmsend);
        printf("\n");

}

void pr_times(clock_t clktck, clock_t real, struct tms *start, struct tms *end) {
        printf("real:%7.2f\n",  real/(double)clktck);
        printf("user:%7.2f\n",  (end->tms_utime - start->tms_utime) / (double)clktck); // this line
        printf("sys:%7.2f\n",   (end->tms_stime - start->tms_stime) / (double)clktck);  // and this line
        printf("cuser:%7.2f\n", (end->tms_cutime- start->tms_cutime)/ (double)clktck);
        printf("csys:%7.2f\n",  (end->tms_cstime- start->tms_cstime)/ (double)clktck);
}

My question is, by this scheme of command execution, is it possible to have user/sys time more than zero (and how) or always these two values is zero (becuase executed as forked(child process) ) ?
I execute the program like following
./a.out "sleep 10" "find / -name a* 1>/dev/null 2>&1" 'bash -c "for ((i=0;i<1000000;i++)); do :; done;" '


What if you don't divide by clktck? Do you get non-zero values then?

It is only to convert time as second

I understand that's why you're doing it, but do you get non-zero results if you keep the raw values?

No, they are all zero

I tried ./testtimes "sleep 10" and the output was real:  10.00 and everything else was 0.

The find command gets an error if you have any files beginning with a in your directory, which you don't see because you're redirecting stderr to /dev/null. Put a* in quotes to prevent the error.

Anyway, the code works fine for me. If you're getting all zeroes, there's a bug in the times() function on your OS.

Which command do you executed by a.out? The same that I sent?

But also in APUE, also user/sys time values are all zero!!

I gave my executable a different name (testtimes instead of a.out) but other than that I executed the same commands.  I also changed sleep 10 to sleep 2 so I wouldn't have to wait so long.

You mean, You can see value greater than zero for sys/user time  (and not for childs) for the process ?!

For the for loop I get real:   1.97 user:   0.00 sys:   0.00 cuser:   1.96 csys:   0.00

By this type of command execution, I think always user time and sys time will be zero. Becuase it is executed as child process
